# Deleting data from sqlite database from JavaFX GUI

Tags: sqlite, javafx

I'm trying to figure out how to make a delete button to work that deletes data from a sqlite database.I managed to delete a row from the tableview.

The only way I managed to successfully delete data is to specify the query which row to delete.So the question is what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the part of the code that I'm having problem with:

```
package Medic;

import dbUtil.dbConnection;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MedicController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button deleteButton;
    @FXML
    private Button closeButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField id;
    @FXML
    private TextField firstname;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastname;
    @FXML
    private TextField email;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker dob;

    @FXML
    private TableView<PacientiData> ptable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PacientiData, String> idcolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PacientiData, String> firstnamecolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PacientiData, String> lastnamecolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PacientiData, String> emailcolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PacientiData, String> dobcolumn;


    private dbConnection dc;
    private ObservableList<PacientiData> data;
    private String sql = "SELECT * FROM pacienti";


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        this.dc = new dbConnection();
    }

    @FXML
    private void loadStudentData(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();

            this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                this.data.add(new PacientiData(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5)));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error " + ex);
        }
        this.idcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PacientiData, String>("ID"));
        this.firstnamecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PacientiData, String>("firstName"));
        this.lastnamecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PacientiData, String>("lastName"));
        this.emailcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PacientiData, String>("email"));
        this.dobcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PacientiData, String>("DOB"));

        this.ptable.setItems(null);
        this.ptable.setItems(this.data);

    }

    @FXML
    private void addStudent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO pacienti(id,fname,lname,email,DOB) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {

            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);
            statement.setString(1, this.id.getText());
            statement.setString(2, this.firstname.getText());
            statement.setString(3, this.lastname.getText());
            statement.setString(4, this.email.getText());
            statement.setString(5, this.dob.getEditor().getText());
            statement.execute();
            conn.close();


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void clearFields(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        this.id.setText("");
        this.firstname.setText("");
        this.lastname.setText("");
        this.email.setText("");
        this.dob.setValue(null);
    }


    @FXML
    public void handleCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }


    @FXML

    public void deleteButton(ActionEvent event) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.sqlite");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database succesfully");
            int selectedIndex = ptable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            ptable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            String sqldelete =" DELETE FROM pacienti WHERE id = ? ";
            statement.executeUpdate(sqldelete);
            conn.commit();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pacienti ");

            while (rs.next() ) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String fname = rs.getString("fname");
                String lname = rs.getString("lname");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String DOB = rs.getString("DOB");
            }

            rs.close();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHOtd.png)

Comment: Should it be `id = ?`?

Comment: You need to look at some `SQLite` tutorials to better understand what you are trying to do. ->http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/delete/

Comment: Also, since you are a beginner, I suggest you not tamper with `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`.

Comment: Yes,it should be id = ? ,I don't know why it was missing here.
I have looked at that sqlite tutorial before,and also tried it,but didn't really work.

Answer (score 2):

*What your issue is*

This code is a problem because the value of the id to delete is never specified:

```
Statement statement = null;
statement = conn.createStatement();
String sqldelete =" DELETE FROM pacienti WHERE id = ? ";
statement.executeUpdate(sqldelete);
```

If you don't tell it what to delete, how could it possibly know what to delete?

There may be other issues I cannot verify as I cannot try out your complete program on your database, but at least the above is an issue.

*How to fix it*

You should use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and set the ID:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(
    "DELETE FROM pacienti WHERE id = ?"
);
statement.setInt(1, id);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

What the value of `id` should be is not clear from your example. My guess is that you would use something like below, assuming an appropriate id value and accessor method exists in your model class:

```
Student selectedStudent = studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
int id = selectedStudent.getId();
```

*A couple of notes on the proposed solution*

I used an `int` as I don't know how your model expresses IDs, but you could use a `long` if it could be a large number of students or `String` if the ID is a [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

As you don't want the delete to run if there is nothing selected (as there would be nothing to delete), then in you initialize you could bind the disable property of the delete button to the selected items list.

```
 deleteButton.disableProperty().bind(
      Bindings.isEmpty(studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())
 );
```

The code I provided is for a SingleSelectionModel where only a single item is selected for deletion at a time.  If you use a MultipleSelectionModel, then you will need to use getSelectedItems() rather than getSelectedItem() and ensure that you delete all of the selected items, rather than just one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I think I should give some explenation regarding the code(because I wasn't that clear ).
So,the part of the code is from one of the controller files from that application(there are 2 controller for 2 different user ,who can sign in and load and add data to the database).I've added also a screen grab of the tableview (maybe will help to understand whats what).I'll add in the whole code.

Comment: Why do that?  Doesn't this answer already solve your problem?  If not, what is the problem?

Comment: Well ,not really ,I've tried it,and didn't really work.

Comment: "didn't really work" isn't all that helpful.  As far as I can tell the suggested approach in this answer should work.  Some stack trace of the exception you get (assuming there is one) would be helpful.  Also, the code of what didn't work (because the code you posted does not match the code I suggested and the posted code certainly wouldn't work).  You could check that the call to getSelectedItem occurs before you remove the selected item from the table.  All of your other calls use a `dbConnection` class which you don't use for your delete function so there could be a mismatch there.

Comment: I'd advise just ensuring delete works without JavaFX using an adaption of the program suggested by Sedrick: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/delete/.  Perhaps the user you are using doesn't have delete permission on the database.  There could be numerous extraneous things which could cause your issue.

Comment: The types used in your code look like a weird mismatch.  At one point you have `int id = rs.getInt("id");` and at another it's `statement.setString(1, this.id.getText());`.  So which is it, an int or a String?

Comment: Well in the database the id is a String.
I've tried this http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/delete/ and it worked on the same database ,that is in my application that I'm working on(it's a simple sqlite database nothing fancy about it).
"didnt really work" yeah well,it didn't and the wierd thing was that it did'nt even give me a stacktrace exception or something.